# Why is the code taking and giving random numbers when inputted numbers in the range?

Tags: c, calculator

I am making a normal basic calculator in Simple C. I used double to store the numbers and I am inputting 9 and 81 as the numbers yet the code takes some random numbers and uses them to calculate the answer. Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
double i,l,j;
char k;
    loop: printf("Enter integer 1 : ");
    scanf("%i",&i);
    printf("Enter integer 2 : ");
    scanf("%i%*c",&j);
    printf("Enter code for operation  p = +, m = -, s = *, 4 = d  : ");
    scanf("%c%*c",&k);
    switch(k){
        case 'p' : l = i + j; printf("%d + %d = %d\n",&i,&j,&l);
            break;
        case 'm' : l = i - j; printf("%d - %d = %d\n",&i,&j,&l);
            break;
        case 's' : l = i * j; printf("%d * %d = %d\n",&i,&j,&l);
            break;
        case 'd' : l = i / j; printf("%d / %d = %d\n",&i,&j,&l);
    }
    exit: printf("enter \"r\" to continue or \"x\" to exit.....\n");
    char exit_v;
scanf("%c" , &exit_v);
    switch(exit_v){
      case 'r':goto loop;
        break;
      case 'x':return 0;
        break;
     default: { printf("Enter valid arguments..." );
                goto exit;}

        }
}
```

And the output that is coming:

```
Enter integer 1 : 9
Enter integer 2 : 81
Enter code for operation  p = +, m = -, s = *, 4 = d  : p
-511875960 + -511875976 = -511875968
enter "r" to continue or "x" to exit.....
x

[Process completed - press Enter]
```

Why is it taking random integers as input when i am entering number in range?

Comment: what do you esxpect this line to do? 'scanf("%i%*c",&j);'

Comment: [scanf manual](https://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf): `i Matches an optionally signed integer;`. If  you want to read integers declare the variables as int and not double: `int i, l, j;`

Comment: @nivpeled get the number and discard the newline

Comment: You need to use a `double` format specifier for `double` variables, obviously.  You're using an `int` format specifer.  So either change it, or switch to an `int` variable.

Comment: And your `printf` arguments should be the actual values, not pointers.  Turn on compiler warnings and *pay attention to them*.  Why post code here that the compiler has already told you has bugs?

Comment: @Tom it compiled correctly, no error was there

Comment: @Tom or maybe it was my fault

Comment: @Tom even after changing from double to int, its still giving random output numbers

Comment: @Tom the code works now, removed all the "&" from the printf statement

Comment: Try to get your compiler warning level up.  A decent compiler should have caught all of those errors, and given you warnings for them.

Comment: @Tom yep, ill do that, thanks

Answer (score 0):

The fix of your code (edits are informed by commented):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    double i, l, j;
    char k;
loop:
    printf("Enter integer 1 : "); // USE %lf FOR READING DOUBLES
    scanf("%lf", &i);
    printf("Enter integer 2 : ");
    scanf("%lf", &j);
    printf("Enter code for operation  p = +, m = -, s = *, 4 = d  : ");
    scanf("%c", k); // You don't need to use &k to read a single char
    switch (k)
    {
    case 'p':
        l = i + j;
        printf("%lf + %lf = %lf\n", i, j, l); // don't read addresses, get values directly
        // secondly you've used %d to read a double, that's incompatible with the variables,
        // use %lf to read/write doubles
        break;
    case 'm':
        l = i - j;
        printf("%lf - %lf = %lf\n", i, j, l);
        break;
    case 's':
        l = i * j;
        printf("%lf * %lf = %lf\n", i, j, l);
        break;
    case 'd':
        l = i / j;
        printf("%lf / %lf = %lf\n", i, j, l);
    }
exit:
    printf("enter \"r\" to continue or \"x\" to exit.....\n");
    char exit_v;
    scanf("%c", exit_v);
    switch (exit_v)
    {
    case 'r':
        goto loop;
        break;
    case 'x':
        return 0;
        break;
    default:
    {
        printf("Enter valid arguments...");
        goto exit;
    }
}
```

As a programming tip, remember next time that using `goto` statements is a bad practice in coding system.